# unsual behavior when binding checkbox output to an object's property using ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am unable to understand the following behaviour:

Here is my angular code:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
angular.module('myMod',[ ])
    .controller('abc',function($scope) {
        $scope.products = products;

        $scope.printProducts = function(){
            for(var index in $scope.products){
              console.log($scope.products[index].key + " " + $scope.products[index].check);
            }
        };

    });

   var products = [{key:'HERO',check:0}, {key:'MARUTI',check:0}, {key:'TATA',check:0}]; 
   }());
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myMod">
    <div ng-controller="abc">
       <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value='1' ng-false-value='0' ng-model='product.check' ng-click="printProducts()">{{product.key}}{{product.check}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>  
<!-- scripts section -->
<script type="text/javascript" src = "angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "basic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So here I am trying to bind to a property of an object 'check' in this case to the output of my checkbox which when selected returns 1 and when unselected gives a value of 0. However, when I am printing the property in console inside the for loop I am getting unexpected behaviour.

For example : when I selected "HERO" I got this output:
HERO 0 -- > should be 1 here
MARUTI 0
TATA 0

Now when I selected Maruti I got :
HERO 1 
MARUTI 0 -- > should be 1 here
TATA 0

Can anyone please explain whats going on here ?
Link to fiddle(thought u cannot see console output) http://jsfiddle.net/k2wfyj6e/

Comment: your fiddle is currently empty. Besides, your ng-click is part of the same digest cycle as your change in checkbox value and is queued too early in the cycle to recognize the change. Use ng-change instead of ng-click

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`. `ng-click` (Basically the click event underneath) happens too early and the  `change` event fires only after that. Angular listens to the change event to update the model value. So listening to `ng-click` will be too early because angular would not have processed and set the model yet.

So try:-

```
   <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value='1' ng-false-value='0' 
          ng-model='product.check' ng-change="printProducts()">
         {{product.key}}{{product.check}}</label>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/82crsxus/)**

Comment: Ohh I never know about this behaviour,thanks a lot this works like a charm